# PDO MySQL syntax error где его не должно быть

Tags: php, pdo

Господа, день добрый! Столкнулся со странной проблемой. Есть метод

```
public function getResultArray($mode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    $stmt = $this->db_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ?");
    if (!$stmt->execute(array('1')))
        var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

Вар дамп выдает следующую ошибку:

> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "42000" [1]=> int(1064) [2]=> string(149) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1'' at line 1" }

Если руками вместо плейсхолдера вписать 1 то выполняется корректно. Не понимаю, в чем тут ошибка

По итогам планируется вернуть результат FetchAll, однако для ясности вопроса функцию упростил

Comment: а почему строка передается в массиве как параметр?

Answer (score 1):

Всем хорош биндинг аргументов запроса простым массивом в `execute` - просто, компактно. Одна проблема жить мешает - и вот как раз легко в неё вляпаться с limit'ом. И с совершенно непонятным текстом ошибки.

При включенной эмуляции подготовленных выражений ([`PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php), по-умолчанию включена) `execute` подставляет параметры только как строки, даже если PHP знает, что переменная числового типа. Получается

```
... limit '1'
```

На что парсер SQL на стороне СУБД и обижается.

При выключенной эмуляции лимит будет работать нормально, если в `execute` передать число. Дефолтно эмуляция включена, так как не все СУБД, с которыми может работать PDO, поддерживают работу с подготовленными выражениями.

Второе решение - биндить параметры явным вызовом [`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) или [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) с указанием типа. При этом все равно надо передавать число, а не строку с числом, по какой-то причине PDO приводить тип не станет)

```
$stmt->bindValue(1, 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вариант с `bindParam` c преобразованием в `int`:

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT); //$limit - в вашем случае 1
$stmt->execute();
```

Больше примеров посмотрите [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php)